# PostgreSQL syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

```
sql"""copy updateTable
from $path
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<my_access_key_id>;aws_secret_access_key=<my_secret_access_key>'
json '<path_to_s3_repository>'
gzip;""".update().apply()
```

Above command gives

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

when run on spark streaming using scala. What might be the issue? The resultant query runs fine when run from command line.

Comment: Do your access_key_id or secret_access_key strings contain '$1'?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a parameter with `COPY`.

You have to add the literal value of `$path` to the statement string and execute that.

Comment: As I said, you have to create a string that looks like `COPY updatetable FROM '/path/where/file/is' ...` and send that to the database. I don't know anything about scala or spark, but that's the answer from the PostgreSQL side.